# Is possible a connection with different port in each computer?

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection, port

Let's think about an hypothetical environment with two sides:

A) An external server, with an IP 123.123.123.123 and a service running in port 1234.

B) My local server which has port 1234 closed.

How could I do to connect from my local server to the service at 123.123.123.123:1234 without opening my local port 1234?

**NOTE**--> My server is using Ubuntu 12.04 and the service is a MySQL database connection in python.

Comment: You don't open a port publicly when connecting to a service. The port you use will be bound to the opened socket only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a socket, the local port is determined randomly. You don't have to open any particular ports on your client in order to connect. Just make sure that firewall rules don't block out all communications to or from your client.

If you can't seem to be able to connect, look at firewall rules. Also run `netstat` from the command line and see if a connection is established or in some other state to 123.123.123.123 port 1234.